Restarting a Google Cloud COS Container Daily
I'm deploying a container on a COS (Container OS) instance. Very simple.
I want it to restart daily. What's the best way to do this? A simple CRON tab I could setup on the VM? The problem with that is that it'll need to be redone whenever the VM is redeployed.

This may help: Scheduling a VM instance to start and stop

Restarting the COS VM will restart the container. As long as the container was defined as part of the instance's configuration (i.e. --container-image etc.) and not run as an ad hoc container.

Evaluate Schedule a VM instance to start and stop.
Restarting the COS VM will restart the container. As long as the container was defined as part of the instance's configuration (i.e. --container-image etc.) and not run as an ad hoc container once the image was running.

Cron Jobs on VMs are not recommended for Containers, because running a Cron Job on the VM itself creates a direct dependency between the Job and the VM. This means if the VM restarts, then we lose Cron Job. Containers can be restarted or destroyed without affecting the overall application state, Cron Job on the VM doesn't respect this behavior. So Cron Job on the VM itself isn't ideal for container deployments because it's tied to the VM and not the Container itself.
You can set up a Cron Job in Kubernetes, which is a built-in feature so that it will be helpful to restart the pods. Refer to Running Automated Tasks with a CronJob for more details.
Use a Cron Job, but not to run your pods, but to schedule a Kubernetes API command that will restart the deployment everyday (kubectl rollout restart). That way if something goes wrong, the old pods will not be down or removed.
Also make sure that you are specifying the correct namespace and the pod has the correct permissions to interact with the k8s API. Because the k8s API authorization to pods is typically done via service accounts. Also You would need to give it permissions to access the API, that means making a ServiceAccount and some RBAC policy objects (Role, RoleBinding) and then set serviceAccountName in your pod spec there.
To restart the pod daily please execute the below,
LivenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - exit $(test $(date +%H) -eq 3 && echo 1 || echo 0)
  failureThreshold: 1
  initialDelaySeconds: 3600
  periodSeconds: 60

Where 86400 is a desired period in seconds (1 restart per day in this example).
Similar to above, you can also use other workarounds like below :
Stackdriver Monitoring: Provides flexible restart scheduling based on custom metrics. Google Cloud Run: Simple and efficient for stateless, scalable applications.
